# Pointer from one class to outer class?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist, subclass

I have an ArrayList of objects, which are used in subclasses of a helperclass. I'm sending the data needed to the subclass, eg `new subclass(ArrayListObject)`, and these subclasses are handled in a map structure in the helperclass. Since a single ArrayListObject is stored in the helperclass, I assumed it would be linked in the subclasses, which need this object for calculations. However, when changed the ArrayListObject is not changed in the subclasses, from what I'm seeing in the debugger.

Is there a way to make this a pointer to another class variable? Or is the most appropriate way to handle this to make the subclass receive a reference to the helperclass in the constructor, to call a helperclass.getArrayObject method?

Comment: Some code or a [sscce](http://sscce.org/) would be helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to accomplish, a pointer, is not available in Java. To work around this, you should make the `ArrayListObject` a protected field of the helperclass. There are two ways to go from here:

1. If the field is never accessed outside of the class and its subclasses, call `super.mArrayList` whenever you need the value.
2. If the field needs to be accessed everywhere, create a public `getArrayListObject()` that returns the value of the object.

Comment: That's interesting, but that didn't help my problem. The ArrayList is only modified by the helper class and should rarely change.

Comment: If it rarely changes, then scrap the volatility and make a private field with a getter.

Comment: And send a reference to the class in the constructor? Or is there a better way to have a pointer like this?

Comment: see my edit. I think I understand what you're trying to do now

Comment: I would guess that if a inter-class pointer were necessary, you'd have to make your own container class?

Comment: You can create an inner class, yes. An inner class requires an instance of its container class, but it has access to all of its fields and methods.